# How to typescript createAction from redux-toolkit to not get errors

Tags: typescript, saga, redux-toolkit

I need to type some props and arguments Here is part of code. How should I write createAction correctly?

```
const onSubmitHandler = (userFormData: TuserDataFromForm) => {
  console.log("this work");
  // here is error - userFormData
  dispatch(asyncAction(userFormData));
};


function* watchFunc() {
  // here is error - asyncAction.type
  yield takeEvery(asyncAction.type, workFunc);
}


// What should I write instead of any
// to not get error here - dispatch(asyncAction(userFormData)) - in Component
// and here - takeEvery(asyncAction.type, workFunc) - in sagas
const asyncAction: any = createAction("ASYNC_ACTION");
```

Here is full code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/saga-redux-toolkit-actions-reducers-of-slices-2f7tx?file=/src/redux/actions.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redux toolkit types are written with the thought that you should not define them yourself.

Write

```
const asyncAction = createAction<TuserDataFromForm>("ASYNC_ACTION");
```

There is no point of specifying a type for the variable there.

In the future, please check [the API documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAction) in the future - it is almost completely available in TypeScript.

As for usage in saga, do either of

```
  yield takeEvery(asyncAction, workFunc);
// or
  yield takeEvery(asyncAction.match, workFunc);
```

You also might want to take a look at typed-redux-saga as that integrates a lot better with TS:

```
import { take } from "redux-saga/effects";

function* exampleSaga() {
  // cannot be inferred and needs to be manually typed
  const action: IncrementActionType = yield take(slice.actions.incrementBy);
}
```

vs:

```
import { take } from "typed-redux-saga";

function* exampleSaga() {
  // correctly inferred as { payload: number; type: string; }
  const action = yield* take(slice.actions.incrementBy);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I found answer recently that I should type only here
const asyncAction = createAction<TuserDataFromForm>("ASYNC_ACTION");

thnx for detailed answer

I'd like to vote but I don't have enough reputation

Comment: Accepting the answer as correct should be fine ;)